# React Native gradlew clean commant is not working

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

i just formatted my PC and reinstalled the envs for react native.

and after i built a empty project getting weird erros. 
Than i tryed to run `gradlew clean` in android folder and even this code is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you must first go to android directory by:

```
cd android
```

> then use this command:

```
./gradlew clean
```

[image]

> for running again , back to previous directory with:

```
cd ..
```

> and again there use this:

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

first be in the react native project directory the follow the commands one by one:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx react-native run-android
```

tell me if it helps